# Existence of an $R>0$ for which the set $f^{-1}(\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq R\})$ is unbounded.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

Consider the entire functions $f(z)=1+z+z^{20}$, $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Then show that $f^{-1}(\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq R\})$ is unbounded for some $R>0$.

So we need to prove the existence of an $R>0$ for which the set $f^{-1}(\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq R\})$ is unbounded. But I failed to find such $R$. Please help me to prove this.

Comment: $f^{-1}(\{|z|\leq R\})\subset \{|z|\leq 3+R\}$ by using the [Lagrange's bound on the roots of a polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrical_properties_of_polynomial_roots#Lagrange's_and_Cauchy's_bounds).

Comment: For $|z| \ge 3$, $|f(z)| \ge |z|^{20} - 1 - |z| \ge |z|^{19}$. Thus for $R \ge 3$, $|f(z)| \le R$ implies $|z| \le R^{1/19}$

Comment: Did the exercise ask you to prove this, or did it ask you to prove or disprove it? If the former, you have a complaint with whoever made it up. If the latter: don't change the problem when you ask about it here!

Answer (score 2):

If $p(z)$ is a nonconstant polynomial, then $\lim_{|z|\to \infty} |p(z)| =\infty.$ This implies $p$ is unbounded on every unbounded set. Your $f$ is such a polynomial. Therefore $f^{-1}(\{z \in \mathbb{C}: |z| \leq R\})$ cannot be unbounded for any $R.$